# is there cryptography algorithm space /input invariant?

Tags: encryption

I'm searching for a cryptographic algorithm that produces the same result for the same input, and if in the input, at position k, there is XXXXXX, then in the output at position k there is always the field YYYYYY.

Comment: I think you need to add more context or details to your question

Comment: That would make it a very weak cipher, wouldn't it? Any block cipher that doesn't take input from the previous block (also eliminate any IV) would do just that.

Comment: does it need to be secure? or are you just playing with encryption. because a cesar cipher would satisfy the criteria i see here. Or the method employed by the enigma machine in WW2

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the most direct answer to your question, but you could segment your input into blocks, and just encrypt the blocks. However, performing this could possibly introduce vulnerabilities caused by being able to exploit how you're segmenting the data (if that method can't be stored in your brain).

Part of how a lot of encryption methods work is they can take a variable length input and create an output that varies size. The only encryption method I can think of that is input invariant the way you describe is a Caesar cipher.